# Center an ImageView in UIScrollView swift during zoom out

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview, swift4

I use the following code to add an imageView in UIScrollView

```
screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
        screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
        radius = min(screenWidth,screenHeight)

        mainScroll.frame =  CGRect(x: 0, y: 90, width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight - 180)
        backView.frame = mainScroll.bounds
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: (screenHeight - radius)/2 - 80, width: radius, height: radius)
         backView.image = imageView.image
        let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.dark)
        let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
        blurEffectView.frame = mainScroll.bounds
        blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        self.view.addSubview(mainScroll)
        self.mainScroll.addSubview(backView)
        self.backView.addSubview(blurEffectView)
        self.backView.addSubview(imageView)
```

The code works fine as expected but when the image is zoomed out, the imageView is no longer centered, however if I zoom in it is centered.

This is The original photo centered correctly[image]

The is the zoomed out image not centered correctly
[image]

any suggestions how to center the image after zooming out

Comment: you have to set minimum zoom scale and set your image view frame same like your scrollview frame and put imageview.center = scrollview.center

Comment: hi I have set my minimum zoom scale already. do I need to do something extra ?

Comment: func setZoomScale(){
        let scaleWidth = Scrollview.frame.size.width / Scrollview.contentSize.width
        Scrollview.minimumZoomScale = scaleWidth
        if ImageView.frame.size.width < Scrollview.frame.size.width {
            print("We have the case where the frame is too small")
            Scrollview.maximumZoomScale = scaleWidth * 2
        } else {
            Scrollview.maximumZoomScale = 1.0
        }
       // Scrollview.zoomScale = scaleWidth + 0.02
        Scrollview.zoomScale = scaleWidth
    }

Comment: Sorry I dont get it. Do I need to call that function or is it called automatically

Comment: you to call this function

Comment: I dont think it is working

Comment: i already use same functionality in my previous app using above code and i have functionality with cropping

Comment: Could you share you code in a reply instead of a comment I just want to follow it thoroughly

Comment: https://github.com/muukii/ZoomImageView refer this